# Unable to get Angular to work on a local domain

Tags: angular, kubernetes, local

[image]I am trying to bring up angular application on custom local domain blog.dev. The angular application is working fine of https://localhost:4200. But on the blog.dev domain, it is not working.

My angular deployment file is given below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: pinakinc/client
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4200
      nodePort: 31000
```

The nginx.conf is given below

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
    application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
    text/javascript;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

The angular.json is given below

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Angular-Mean": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Angular-Mean",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "options": {
            "host": "blog.dev",
            "port": 80
          },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Angular-Mean:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "Angular-Mean:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            
            "browserTarget": "Angular-Mean:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Angular-Mean"
}
```

The host file entry is given below

127.0.5.1 blog.dev

I am using minikube

Comment: I am facing issues while bringing the cluster up. API server is going down frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Things that were done to resolve the issue

1. nginx config file was changed as follows:

   ```
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
        application/javascript 
        application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml 
        application/xml+rss 
        text/javascript;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
      }
    }
   ```

The deployment file is given below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: client-depl
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: pinakinc/client
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 32000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application running on port **4200** so the target port should be **4200** in service also.

So traffic flow like `service port 80 > target port 4200 > container port 4200`

Target point and container port should get matched.

```
- name: client
          image: pinakinc/client
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports: 
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 4200
      nodePort: 31000
```

Comment: Harsh, I get an odd page https://www.sixapart.jp/ when I navigate to blog.dev. Please help

Comment: When I open a incognito session, I get page not found error

Comment: that's some other issues answer is based on the question.feel free to update the status of this question and answer new one with proper details.

Comment: I did a minikube tunnel and now I got nginx bad gateway. Please help me here

Comment: hi pinakin sorry it would be hard to help without the details as said above, you can update the status of this question if resolve your issues and post new question with details and snapshot you are facing.

Comment: I have edited the question. Request you to check